# fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory Ubuntu and Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I have the `opencv` installed in `/usr/include/opencv4` folder

[image: opencv location]

I configured the VSCode as it should be, and the IntelliSense can detect the library.

[image]

The configuration should be correct (I guess)

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/opencv4/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, I get an error:

```sh
fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: If you do `ls -l /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp`, do you see the file or get an error? If it's not there: `sudo apt install libopencv-dev`

Comment: Yes, the file exists as I showed in the question along other files
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151612 Dec 20  2019 /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp`

Comment: Ok, I could see the pictures. Perhaps changing to the C++ compiler instead of using the C compiler changes something?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I really tried cpp, gcc and g++. I guess I shall use normal cmake burden to compile it

Comment: `cpp` isn't a compiler in the normal sense, it's a pre-processor. `gcc` is what you should use for C programs and `g++` is what should be used for C++ programs.

Comment: how does vscode even know how to build this? perhaps try giving an include path that DOES NOT include two stars at the end. by the way, *tabnine* offering completions does *not* imply that anything's configured properly for *compilation*. tabnine could simply offer text completions it has memorized.

Answer (score 4):

After a couple of days, I was able to find out the solution.

It was to add the necessary flags to the build task.

I posted the full sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/wbadry/Simple-OpenCV-CPP-VSCode). Hopefully, it will help someone in the future.

The `task.json` should be

```
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "`pkg-config",
                "--cflags",
                "--libs",
                "opencv4`"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

The missing was to add these arguments

```
"`pkg-config",
"--cflags",
"--libs",
"opencv4`"
```